# What would happen to a Water/Lard Mix under pressure and high heat?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, physical-chemistry

If water is mixed with lard oil and heated (creating some *super-critical* water), how does this affect the volatility of the mixture in comparison if it is a pure mix of either water, or lard oil?

What happens when a mixture of lard oil and water is compressed and then heated to over 800 degrees Fahrenheit almost instantaneously (up to 1200 degrees Fahrenheit)? If it is in a well sealed copper container, would it be volatile enough to burst through the container?

Note: I'm no scientist or chemist, so use of laymen's terms, if possible, would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what *aspect* you are asking about exactly… but **all supercritical liquids are completely miscible with each other**, so you would get one supercritical phase with the mixture of the two… supposing the oil doesn't decompose.

However, [the smoke point of lard is 182°C](http://www.cookingforengineers.com/article/50/Smoke-Points-of-Various-Fats) while the critical temperature of water is 374°C, so what most probably happens is that your lard will burn, **breaking down to glycerol, acrolein and free fatty acids**.

Comment: I edited my question in hopes of clarifying for you... Thank you for your response. I am wanting to know, if it is contained in a soft metal, like copper if it would be volatile enough to burst through the container... And if, the supercritical water and the lard oil combination is more volatile than if it was a pure sample of either liquid. Hope that helps... Thanks again!!

Comment: @TirzahVernon this latter question is a matter also of pressure, requiring dimensional figures for the fluid volume and container volume.  If the container is not a primitive (e.g. cylinder) then be sure to indicate.  You may want to ask this question in [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com)